# PHP Code Separation

Tags: php, model-view-controller, design-patterns

Bad idea mixing HTML and PHP?

I was reading this [tutorial](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/198226-code-separation/) and it seems like code separation is a more elegant design incorporating some sort of MVC structure.  One thing that is on my mind is - Is it really acceptable to mix a little bit of HTML and PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's acceptable to mix HTML and PHP as long as you're doing it for presentation purposes. In an MVC structure, you only mix PHP with HTML in a view, and only for things needed by the view.

Never mix business logic with HTML.

Comment: So it's fine for presenting stuff and the other back end PHP stuff should have no HTML in it right?

Comment: Depending on what you mean by back end... As a rule of thumb, it's fine to use PHP as a templating language. Use `foreach`, `if`, variables obtained from controllers, etc, but do not make queries, create objects, etc, this is a controller's job.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - it's completely acceptable to mix HTML and PHP even in MVC Frameworks.  It's more than acceptable - it's expected.

The "code separation" you're probably talking about is dealing with more the TYPE of PHP you're putting in your HTML code.  For example, in most MVC frameworks, you keep your logic for retrieving the data, and your actual connections to retrieve the data in different files than your HTML - but in your HTML you still need things like PHP loops, includes...etc

Answer (score 1):

Before the PHP MVC frameworks came into existence, that is how conventional PHP websites existed in the first place :) It is completely acceptable.

Comment: If people wrote spaghetti code, that doesn't mean spaghetti code is acceptable. It's ugly, unmaintanable, hard to read, error prone, where do I begin to list all the disadvantages?

Comment: people who write "spaghetti code"s, will write those in MVC also.

Answer (score 1):

The "tutorial" that you included has an example.php file that is almost unreadable because of the ridiculous way that it deals with abstraction.

I think by and large people worry about this too much, I tend to separate fairly heavily just because I think it helps the way that I program to have different elements of the application (PHP/CSS/HTML/JS) in different files.

Having said that there are times when it's just too much. There's nothing wrong with `echo '<strong>'.$title.'</strong>';` just like there's nothing wrong with `<strong><?=$title?></strong>`.

The one thing that I would say is try not to confuse the two (i.e. separate logic from presentation in some files but then get lazy and don't do it in others) as this will most likely end up with you looking through a number of files to try and find where your `get_user_from_email()` function or whatever is.

Obviously if you're using a specific design pattern  then you should follow the rules of that pattern. MVC should have a seperation of business logic and presentation.